# InDesign: How to set magazine layout pages for PDF export?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, print-production

I am working on a magazine design and my pages are set up as spreads that also has bleed. I have some questions about this and also some other questions regarding to preparing file for print.

1. Do I need to work in InDesign as single pages for all magazine instead of spreads or I can switch that at the end to adjust content bleed? Asking this because if I will export as single page PDF, the part of inside bleed will not appear in that PDF file, how can I fix this to export single pages correctly with bleed on all four sides? Magazine will also have full spread photos, does this matter in this situation?
2. If printer didn't give exact CMYK colour profile, but I know that it will be printed on uncoated matte paper, is that fine to choose one of the uncoated colour profiles and work with it? This seems fine until I started to think about maximum colour % for it, because it could be from 300 till 340.
3. When exporting all pages into single page PDF document, do I need in the "Colour conversion" field set to "No colour conversion" or "Covert to Destination (Preserve numbers)"?

Comment: 1. By default, a spreads document will bleed on all sides when exporting as single pages. I don't bother with color profiles anymore so can't answer to 2 & 3.

Comment: I think it's just human nature to ask a question rather than search. However, if you search this site you'll find an exceptional amount of information related to your questions. In fact, if you merely look to on the right side of *this page*, you'll see several "related" questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming that your magazine is being perfect bound, then the general practice is to design in spreads, then split to individual pages before exporting. If EVERY spread has a cross-over image, then this doesn't matter because it will automatically export the bleed correctly. It will only be wrong if you have artwork stopping at the gutter (i.e. left page is an image and right page is all white). If it is being saddle stitched, the bleed in the gutter is irrelevant.
2. I would not adjust the color profile, let your printer do this for you (which they will do anyways in their rip). Or request an InDesign PDF preset from them.
3. If you request the PDF preset from the printer, this will take care of that question. But "Covert to Destination (Preserve numbers)" is the standard.